# Windows 2003, how to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) without an IIS

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, csr

I have a Windows 2003 that hosts a Citrix Secure Gateway service. (It is a reverse proxy that adds SSL to my otherwise unencrypted connections)

It doesn't depend on IIS that indeed may also be stopped. 
But for one fact: as an SSL proxy, this "secure gateway" must be provided with certificates.
When it comes to create a CSR, i need to revive my IIS, generate the CSR for the CA and install the certificate returned back from the CA (that is, process the csr pending request).
I am wondering if there is another tool in order to do such things because i can easily imagine Windows servers without IIS installed on them and I would like to have a procedure to manage those cases too.

Answer (score 2):

The command line tool [certreq](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725793(v=ws.10).aspx) is available on most versions of Windows (2000,2003,2008,2012), and can be used to generate and accept requests.

Comment: ok, i have verified that the tool is available on Win 2003 from SP1. Just one question, to clarify, the certificate request procedure is NOT available from certificates mmc snapin (as i suppose)?